# Not getting any output or errors ghostscript python

Tags: python, ghostscript

No tif image is being generated anyone see the error?  I am not receiving any errors. I am now seeing the message that ghosscript is running, still not getting an output tif though. from output I am now getting 'GPL Ghostscript 9.02 (2011-03-30)\nCopyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.\nThis software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.\n'   getting closer

Edited made changes as suggested by comments**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE,STDOUT

output = Popen([
    r'C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.02\bin\gswin32c.exe',
   '-dNOPAUSE',
   '-dBATCH',
   '-sDEVICE=tiffg4',
    '-dDEBUG',
   '-r196X204',
   '-sPAPERSIZE=a4',
   '-sOutputFile=%s' % (r'C:\Python25\pdfmining\page.tif'),
    '%s' %(r'C:\Python25\pdfmining\nca.pdf'),

],stdout=PIPE,stderr = STDOUT).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Have you tried running it by hand from the command line?

Comment: the formatting is slightly different but I can try, are you suggesting that to try and find errors?

Comment: Absolutely. Many programs detect whether or not they are being run from the command line and modify their output accordingly. You might also want to lose the `-q` switch since that may be suppressing useful information. I looked for its opposite -- some sort of verbosity switch -- but couldn't find it in the online docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see an input file for your command. Add the full path to an input file (PDF, PostScript, Encapsulated PostScript or AI) as the last argument, and your TIFFs should be generated...

Also, remove the `-q`. It tells Ghostscript to remain *'quiet'*.

Lastly, you could add a `-dDEBUG` to your commandline. It tells Ghostscript to output lots of debugging information.

Comment: thanks i think that's the underlying problem i followed normal format but forgot to seperate the two files with a comma, i added debug and made the change to my code to now have the last file as the last argument.  From the debug output I am getting this error:  Ghostscript 9.02: **** Could not open the file "C:\\Python25\\pdfmining\\page.tif" .\n%Resolving: [6 0]\nError: /ioerror in --showpage-..... etc I am not sure if the output with the double \\ is merely for output or a formatting issue.  Which also doesn't make sense because that is the output file?  It sould be creating it.  Any though

Comment: nvm just fixed it :), got rid of the " " '-sOutputFile="%s" around s,

Comment: @Kurt Pfeifle debug info you do not have time to read. Is it possible to write it in a log file?

Answer (score 1):

Some issues with your code:

1. You need to use raw strings so that the backslashes will not be treated as escape sequences.

   e.g. `r'C:\Python25\pdfmining\nca.pdf'` instead of `'C:\Python25\pdfmining\nca.pdf'`.
2. The `self._` looks out of place here: `'self._C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.02\bin'`
3. It looks like you're passing the directory and executable filename as separate arguments. They should be together as the path of the executable file.
4. You may also want to capture the `stderr` so that you see the error messages, for example by using `stderr=STDOUT` to join stderr output with stdout.

Comment: made change, still not outputting file will add above in code to reflect it.

Comment: will change code accordingly and combine path and executable name, not seeing what you mean by adding the STDOUT, getting NameError: name 'STDOUT' is not defined, when adding like stdout above.

Comment: @user you need to import STDOUT from the subprocess module. BTW you didn't add a raw string for the filename.

Comment: yes now with stdout am seeing an error message in output at least

Comment: interjay, what is the protocol for editing, should i leave the original then have a second version of changed code below?

Comment: I would have left the original code and then showed the good code.